# separate same line numbers from multiple files

Tags: text-processing

I have a collection of 2000 text files (5 column and 1000 row) and I would like to create multiple separate files meaning that the first file contains first lines of multiple txt files. The second file contains second lines of multiple txt files.

I have used this below `awk` command, but that works just for one line.

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print, $0}' *.txt >output.txt
```

**Edit**:

Please see the attachment.

[image]

Comment: elaborate your question. You have written `all fist lines` twice

Comment: Kindly explain clearly your question is totally confusing

Comment: Wasn't there something just like this a couple of days ago? Is it a homework assignment somewhere?

Comment: I merged the follow-up answer into the question as an edit, but I don't understand the question well enough to rewrite it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=0
while read -r line; do
     COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
        sed -n "$COUNT{p;q}" test1.txt >> solution$COUNT.txt
        sed -n "$COUNT{p;q}" test2.txt >> solution$COUNT.txt
done < test1.txt
```

Comment: Since the question is about multiple files, a loop over the files would be nice.